# Compare NSFileModificationDate of previous Backup

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, nsfilemanager

Here am creating backup of my database. But i don want to jus keep creating backups. i need to check the NSModificationDate property of the most recently created backup database and have to create new backup only if the database is modified. Can anyone help me on this.

```
-(IBAction)createdb:(id)sender
{
DatabaseList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSDate *currentDateTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddyyyyHHmmss"];
NSString *dateInStringFormated = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDateTime];

dbNameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UW_%@.db",dateInStringFormated];

NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentFolderPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *dbName = @"UnitWiseDB.db";
NSString *dbPath1 = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbNameString];
NSString *backupDbPath = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];

NSError *error = nil;

NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:backupDbPath error:&error];
NSLog(@"Persistent store size: %@ bytes", [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize]);
NSLog(@"Modification Date: %@ ",[fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate]);

if ( ![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dbPath1])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:backupDbPath toPath:dbPath1 error:nil];
}
NSLog(@"DBPath.......%@",dbPath1);

NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentFolderPath error:nil];

for (NSString *s in fileList)
{
    NSLog(@"Backup.....%@", s);
    [DatabaseList addObject:s];
}

[ListViewTableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Why not create a table in the database and set a column to non-zero if changes have been made.  Then reset this value when a backup is performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking modification , you can use a simple trick as described by trojanfoe.

When ever you are modifying i mean adding/ removing/ editing any record  in database , set a `BOOL` flag = YES and store in `NSUSERDEFAULTS` , after creating the backup, set the flag to NO.